# Start One drive by intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onedrive

I have one drive application installed from google play.
I am trying to start it via intent:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.skydrive");
startActivity(intent);
```

**How can I find out whether there are some possibilities for other intent parameters?**

I would like to open One drive application in **particular folder** (/test/focus)

Answer (score 1):

Go this way.

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.skydrive");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will find suitable activity corresponding to the package name.